# Why Elsif not Else If In PLC programming

Tags: programming-languages, plc

Im a PLC programmer and I am wondering why the reserved word elsif (ie without the E ) is used.  I know that elseif or any other combination is not used as reserved words.  Is there a history to use this in other Languages. If so why? just to save on typing cause for me I seem to make the mistake of typing the e probably 5 times a day.

Answer (score 6):

Programming languages have never quite agreed on this. Various common languages use:

```
else if
elseif
elsif
elif
```

and perhaps others. There's often no good reason for the language designer choosing one over another.

<sup>(Bonus points if you can name some languages that use each of the above forms!)</sup>

Comment: C, PHP, Perl, CPP. Clearly `elsif` is superior.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what type of PLC you are programming, I just found out rockwells structured text uses elsif, and Ada did but thats not really for PLCs is it?

I am told it's Syntactic sugar, the elsif is there so you don't have your code cluttered up by lots of brackets

```
if cond1 then 
   funct1 
elsif cond2 then
   funct2 
elsif cond3 then
   funct3 
else
   funct4 
end if
```

becomes

```
if cond1 then
   funct1 
else (if cond2 then
       funct2 
        else (if cond3 then
         funct3 
          else funct4 
))
end if
```

As far as the origin goes my guess would be it has just stuck around since Ada or whatever was before that.

Comment: Yeah I use rockwell I manly make the mistake cause my mind thinks elseif and I just react with an e.

Answer (score 0):

Pascal is the father of Structured Text (or SCL as called by Siemens) used in PLCs.